# Need to check sampling events using alpha and log 10 method in rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm calculating percent of events having null data in my data sample using 'dot' method. The Sample data is:

```
Students    Percent_Of_Null_data   Total_data
Student1       0.590                25988893
Student2       1.20                 179604883
Student3       0.710                263405
Student4       0.545                147438932
Student5       0.413                361275405
```

The code which i'm using for dot method is:

```
ggplot(Students_data, aes(x=Students, y=Percent_Of_Null_data)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", fill = "orange") +
geom_point(aes(size= Total_data))
```

I'm trying to implement the same for alpha and log 10 method.

Since I'm very new to Rstudio, can someone help me in doing the same with alpha and log 10 methods?

Comment: What is *alpha method*? Are you talking about the transparency level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

log function summary in r

Basic grammar :

```
log(x, base=y)
```

Example :

```
log(4, base = 2)
[1] 2
log(1000, base = 10)
[1] 3
```

Your case :

```
ggplot(Students_data, aes(x=Students, y=log(Percent_Of_Null_data, base = 10))) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", fill = "orange") +
geom_point(aes(size= Total_data))
```